# Rails Conditional Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements, actionmailer

I have a Rails app which tracks calls.  Each time a new call is generated, I send an email to the staff that is assigned to aka the unit's medics (which is an association) via the medic_email field and I cc the new call to address@domain.com.

Currently what I have is working fine, but I would like to add a conditional in the mailer somehow to change the cc: address based off of a call's region (which is an association between call and region).  So all calls in the Houston region are delivered to the medics assigned to the call and cc'd to houston@domain.com and all calls in the Dallas region are delivered to the medics assigned to the call and cc'd to dallas@domain.com

What would be the correct way to setup a conditional in the mailer to do this based off of the current code I have written.  Below are some excepts which might help explain the question better.  If anything is unclear, please let me know and I will revise my question.

**call_mailer-excerpt**

```
  def new_call(medic, call)
    @call = call
    @medic = medic

    mail to: [@medic.medic_email], :cc => "alerts@domain.com", subject: "New Call: #{@call.incident_number}"
  end
```

**call.rb-excerpt**

```
has_many :call_units
has_many :units, through: :call_units
belongs_to :region

  def send_mail(mail_type)
    units.each do |unit|
      CallMailer.send(mail_type, unit.incharge,  self).deliver
      CallMailer.send(mail_type, unit.attendant, self).deliver
    end
  end
```

**region.rb-excerpt**

```
attr_accessible :area
  has_many :calls
```

**calls_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.new(params[:call])
    @call.dispatched_by = current_user.username

     if @call.save
      if @call.unit_ids.present?
        @call.send_mail(:new_call)
        send_new_sms
        redirect_to calls_path, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully created.".html_safe
      else
        redirect_to calls_path, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully created.".html_safe
      end
      else
        render :new
     end
  end
```

**unit.rb**

```
has_many :call_units
has_many :calls, through: :call_units
belongs_to :attendant, :foreign_key => :attendant_id, :class_name => 'Medic'
belongs_to :incharge, :foreign_key => :incharge_id, :class_name => 'Medic'
```

**medic.rb-excerpt**

```
has_many :units
has_many :units_attendant_name, :foreign_key => :attendant_id, :class_name => 'Unit'
has_many :units_incharge_name, :foreign_key => :incharge_id, :class_name => 'Unit'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to add a "copy_mail" column to the Region table.

```
rake db:migrate AddCopyMailToRegion copy_mail:string
```

Populate it with the right email addresses, then reference it in the mailer...

```
mail to: [@medic.medic_email], :cc => @call.region.copy_mail, subject: "New Call: #{@call.incident_number}"
```

Comment: This is rather clever and very straight forward.  And it allows me to scale as I add regions instead of having some crazy if/else/elsif conditionals in the mailer.  I'm going to try this out and give it a whirl.  Thanks so much for your quick response, I'll let you know if I have any questions :)

Comment: No problem!  :) If you like my answer feel free to vote it up or accept it (the checkbox to the left of the answer).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This was so much simpler than trying to include some wacky conditional in the mailer.  I tried it in my dev environment and it worked perfectly.  Just pushed it out to production so things should work smoothly.  I marked your answer and upvoted it.  Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: Cool and thanls :)  You probably have this covered but don't forget to populate the new field in the production system.

Comment: Yes sir, I made sure to populate the region email fields with the proper email addresses in the production database. :)  It was the first thing I did after deploying.  Thanks for reminding me though.